# Modular Mixed-Radix Gray Code Generation with Hamming-weight restriction

Tags: c, combinations, combinatorics

For a project I need to enumerate all vectors of `F_q^n` (the vector space of dimension `n` over the finite field with `q` elements, where `q` is a prime number) in a special way.

I need to enumerate them in a (mixed radix) [Gray Code](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gray_code) like manner, i.e. each consecutive elements differ in only one position. An algorithm achieving this is Algorithm H of Knuth's `The Art of Computer Programming` Volume 4A, in 7.2.1.1.

But additionally to this, I only want to enumerate vectors which fulfill a Hamming-Metric restriction like `hw(v) < w`, with `v \in F_q^n` and `w` is a known bound, which is much smaller that `n`.

Is there some way to adapt Algorithm H to also fulfill this constraint?

Example c code of algorithm H:

```c
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define n (4)
const uint32_t q = 3;

uint32_t a[n + 0];
uint32_t f[n + 1];
int32_t o[n + 0];
uint32_t m[n + 0];


void print_state() {
    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        printf("%u", a[i]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}


int main() {
    // init the variables
    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        a[i] = 0;
        f[i] = i;
        o[i] = 1;
        m[i] = q;
    }
    f[n] = n;

    while (1) {
        print_state();
        uint32_t j = f[0];
        f[0] = 0;
        if (j == n)
            break;

        a[j] = (int32_t)a[j] + o[j];

        if ((a[j] == 0) || (a[j] == m[j] - 1)) {
            o[j] = 0-o[j];
            f[j] = f[j+1];
            f[j+1] = j + 1;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Seems like a hard problem to me. You could approach it as follows. First create a list of all vectors that are allowed by the extra restriction. Then convert the list into a undirected graph where an edge between `u` and `v` exists iff `u` and `v` differ in only one position. Then find a Hamiltonian cycle in the graph. The problem you face is that there may not *be* a Hamiltonian cycle. Even if the cycle exists, it may be hard to find it (since in general, the [Hamiltonian cycle problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamiltonian_path_problem) is a hard problem).

Comment: For example, consider `n=2` and `q=2` and `hw(v) < 2`. The only allowed vectors are (0,0), (0,1) and (1,0). There's no way to make a Gray Code from those vectors.

Comment: of cause: (0,1) -> (0,0) -> (1,0). Those sequences never start with the all zero vector.

Comment: Gray codes are cyclic, so it's `(0,1) -> (0,0) -> (1,0) -> (0,1) -> ...` which is not valid. The code you start with doesn't matter in the least. btw, every example in the wikipedia article that you linked starts with the all zero vector.

Comment: ah good point. But in my case that's  not necessary, as I build the sequence once, save it. And from thereon I can look the elements up.

Comment: This question may be better suited to https://cs.stackexchange.com or https://cstheory.stackexchange.com . This is not really a C question, as tagged.